# Wrong script behavior for output time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I get data from the `json` file. They have this form (these are messages).

```
[
    {
        "time": "1499877171",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499877174",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499877175",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    }
]
```

("time" in seconds)

The script should only display messages for the last hour. It do this, but the time it displays on the screen is not correct.

It should be like this: the user goes to the page, he see messages in the last hour, he rewrites, all new messages are displayed.

But I get so that the messages for the last hours are shown with the wrong time and in addition the output of messages in what is not correct.

All messages are displayed in the last hour, but I need that new messages be displayed immediately and not shown if they have already been shown (as it is now)

```js
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
//I take messages from the file
callback([
    {
        "time": "1499877171",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499877174",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499877175",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "qwe"
    }
]);
function callback(respond) {
  setTimeout(function tick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
      var data = respond[i];
      var now = Date.now();
      var diff_time = Math.floor(now - ((data.time) * 1000));
      if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
        var new_date = new Date(diff_time);
        var res = [new_date.getHours(), new_date.getMinutes(), new_date.getSeconds()].map(function(x) {
          return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
        }).join(":");
        var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
        $('#messages').append(rowClone);
        $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
        $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
        $('.message', rowClone).html(data.message);
        $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());
      }
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 3600000);
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 255px;
  max-height: 255px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table#messages {
  min-height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

tr {
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
}

td.time,
td.name {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

input#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 95px;
  background: #635960;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="easyForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

So, i have two little questions:

1.Why is the time displayed incorrectly?

2.How can I do a check: has this message already been displayed?

Comment: Use incremental id on each item....store highest id each time then filter based on stored id to see what is new vs what has already been seen. Store in localStorage if needed

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong time"?  Is the time formatted incorrectly?  Is it off by some timespan?  Is it showing the time from a different message?  What is the expected outcome and what is the actual outcome?  This will help determine what might need to be adjusted.

Comment: @TLS I mean that when translating time back into the readable version, something goes wrong and it does not display correctly (not the time the message was written)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from charlietfl, you'll need to store some identifier for each message when it's displayed, and then check that list before displaying messages.  If you control the system that provides the json data, you could do the tracking there and then provide only the messages that need to be displayed in the json data.  When displaying the messages, update the tracking mechanism to indicate the message has been displayed.  (The question is broad, so the answer is equally so).

Regarding the date display issue, I think this line is probably causing the troubles:

```
var new_date = new Date(diff_time);
```

You're creating a new `Date` from a difference between two dates.  The value of `diff_time` will be "very small" relative to similar values that represent current dates/times.  What you probably want to do is something like this (a few lines shown for context):

```
....
var now = Date.now();
var time_ms = data.time * 1000;              // Convert to milliseconds
var diff_time = Math.floor(now - time_ms);   // Calculate difference
if (diff_time <= 3600000) {                  // Check range
    var new_date = new Date(time_ms);        // Create Date from milliseconds
    ....
```

Note that the `time` value from the json data is converted to milliseconds (as you did before) and also used when calculating the time difference.  After determining the message is in the acceptable time window, create a new `Date` object from `time_ms` to get the correct timestamp display.